# Sencha: How to use data from one file to another

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im new at this sencha thingy and im trying to experiment a bit with it. I've been making some very simple tests and now i've reached the point where i want to pass the data from one file to another. To make it easier to understand im trying to get the data from the following text box to make a simple filter tool.
[image]

the textfield has been created in the following piece of code in the file Filters.js

```
Ext.define('Prj01Filtro.view.main.Filters', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'Filters',
    alias: 'form.formFilter',
    
    requires: [
        'Prj01Filtros.view.main.FilterController'
    ],

    controller: 'controllerFilter',
    
    items:[
        {
            margin: '0 0 10 0',
            buttons: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Filter',
                    name: 'textFieldSearch'
                }, {
                    name: 'buttonSearch',
                    text: 'Buscar',
                    listeners: {
                        click: 'onClickFilter'
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'buttonRemoveFilter',
                    text: 'X',
                    listeners: {
                        click: 'onClickRemove'
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
```

The code of the buttons have been located in a file named FilterController.js

```
Ext.define('Prj01Filtros.view.main.FilterController',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.controllerFilter',

    onClickFilter: function() {
        //Code to apply the filter
    },

    onClickRemove: function() {
        //code to remove the filter
    }
})
```

Finally the code of the table is located in a file named List.js

```
Ext.define('Prj01Filtros.view.main.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainlist',
    plugins: 'gridfilters',

    requires: [
        'Prj01Filtros.store.Personnel'
    ],

    title: 'Personnel',

    store: {
        type: 'personnel'
    },

    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', align: 'left', filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }},
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1, align: 'left', filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }},
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex: 1, align: 'left', filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }},
    ],

    listeners: {
        select: 'onItemSelected'
    },
});
```

So my goal is to make a function in FilterController.js that can be called from Filters.js which sets the value for the filters applied in the columns of List.js but im kind of stuck on how to set the value property for the filter from the function that i have created. If someone knows how to do it i would appreciate the help. Thanks!

I've tried many things but since im new to sencha im pretty much sure that they were incorrect anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to study [View Models & Data Binding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html) and [ViewModel Internals](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/application_architecture/view_model_internals.html) sections of Ext JS documentation. These are among the most powerful features of Ext JS so it good to develop a deep understanding.

For you current question, you need to access the **store** behind your `List` view  to manage the filters, not the list itself. Once you get the store, you can set / clear the filters with [setFilters](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#placeholder-setFilters) and [clearFilter](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-clearFilter) methods on the store:

```
store.setFilter([{
  property: 'email',
  value: '<search term here>',
  operator: 'like'
}]);
```

```
store.clearFilter();
```

To easily access the store, define the store in the view model of a view that is **above both `List` and `Filters` view**. This is the important part because this way you can take advantage of inheriting the view model from the container parent. Let's say you have a panel which contains both `List` and `Filters`. Define the store in the view model:

```
stores: {
  personnel: {
    type: 'personnel'
  }
}
```

Use `bind` config when assigning the store in your `List`:

```
Ext.define('Prj01Filtros.view.main.List', {
  ...
  bind: {
    store: '{personnel}'
  }
  ...
});
```

After all this, you can access the store from the `Filters` view controller's methods:

```
onClickFilter: function() {   
  this.getViewModel().getStore('personnel').setFilters(...);      
}
```

You need the get the value the user entered into the field. You can access it from the controller with querying the textfield component, but you can also do it with the view model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But im having a little issue, when you say access the store behind the list, how would i have to do that? As I said im kinda new to all this and there is so much stuff that its overwhelming.

Comment: `this.getViewModel().getStore()` will get the store, or if you get somehow the `Ext.grid.Panel`, you can user `getStore()` on it as well.